# How to access array of dictionaries in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I have `array` which contains `dictionaries`. This is how I try to access the array.

Whats the wrong of this?

```
let aWeather: Dictionary = arrWeatherDeatils[indexPath.row]! as!Dictionary
```

When I use this code, xcode shows this error:

```
Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: Provide some more code?

Comment: is your Array arrWeatherDeatils is WS response ??

Comment: No it's not a direct WS response. I read from a plist in to arrWeatherDeatils

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292679/command-failed-due-to-signal-segmentation-fault-11-due-to-tableviewcontroller 

This might help

Answer (score 1):

```
let aWeather: Dictionary<AnyObject,AnyObject> = arrWeatherDeatils[indexPath.row]! as! Dictionary<AnyObject,AnyObject>
```

Answer (score 1):

Write dictionary like below,

```
 let aWeather : NSDictionary = arrWeatherDeatils.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
```

To solve segmentation fault:11 error,

Try this, go to Build Settings -> Swift Compiler - Code generation, set Optimisation Level to None.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Why should i use NSDictionary? If use NSDictionary, can I access the dictionary objects as this cell!.lblAvgHome.text = (aWeather["home"]!["avg"]!)

Comment: yes like, cell!.lblAvgHome.text = aWeather.valueForKey("home")?.valueForKey("avg") as! String

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrWeatherDeatils = [
    "Sunny": 76.0,
    "Chilly": 22.1,
    "Warm": 37.0
]

var typeList: [String] {
    get {
        return Array(arrWeatherDeatils.keys)
    }
}
```

Then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //note I did not check for nil values. Something has to be really         let row = indexPath.row //get the array index from the index path
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let myRowKey = typeList[row] //the dictionary key
    cell.textLabel!.text = myRowKey
    let myRowData = arrWeatherDeatils[myRowKey] //the dictionary value
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = String(format: "%6.3f",myRowData!)
    return cell
}
```